# nsis uninstaller doesn't remove links

Tags: nsis, shortcut, uninstallation

I have this issue:
in the installer sections I have this;

```
Section "Start Menu Shortcuts"
    SetShellVarContext current
    CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\myProgram"
    CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\myProgram\myProgram.lnk" "$INSTDIR\myProgram.exe" 
    CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\myProgram\Uninstall myProgram.lnk" "$INSTDIR\myProgram-Uninstall.exe"
SectionEnd

Section "Desktop Shortcut"
    SetShellVarContext current
    CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\myProgram.lnk" "$INSTDIR\myProgram.exe"
SectionEnd
```

and it works fine, I have the icon on the desktop and the icon plus the uninstall icon on the start\programs... tree

the uninstaller section is like this:

```
SetShellVarContext current
Delete "$DESKTOP\myProgram.lnk"
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\myProgram\myProgram.lnk"
Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\myProgram\Uninstall myProgram.lnk"
RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\myProgram"
```

and the desktop link was deleted, but the other folder with the links not..
any ideas?

the folder where is stored is this *(i'm on win 7 64 bits)*:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have [RequestExecutionLevel](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#requestexecutionlevel) in your script? Without it Windows might do some [compatibility hacks](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Shortcuts_removal_fails_on_Windows_Vista) with your shortcuts.

If that does not help, try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), it might be able to shed some light on the issue...

Comment: thankyou! i've added the RequestExecutionLevel admin and now works... also that if my currentuser is administrator.. thanks

Comment: I don't know why "RequestExecutionLevel admin" doesn't work for me, but "SetShellVarContext all" does...

Comment: @Sorayuki It should prevent the compatibility shim from kicking in but will not remove the compatibility shortcuts that might already exist...